# Reg - Data Read from Byte Stream

Tags: java

I'm trying to read a file with normal Text data using a byte stream. And I understand that in a byte stream each byte will be read one by one. Hence if I read the data `Hi How are you!!!!!!` in a the Text file through a byte stream then it should give me the Unicode equivalent of the each character but instead it gives me a different output which doesn't maps to utf or ascii equivalent.

Below is my Program

```
package files;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class FileBaiscs {    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {        
        String strPath = "D:\\Files\\New.txt";  
        File objSrcFile = new File (strPath);           
        if (objSrcFile.exists()==false)
        {   
            System.out.println("The Source File is not Present");
            System.exit(0);
        }       
        FileInputStream objIpStream = new FileInputStream(objSrcFile);          
        while ((objIpStream.read())!=-1)
        {
            System.out.println(objIpStream.read());
        }           
        objIpStream.close();
    }
}
```

The output in my console is:

```
105
72
119
97
101
121
117
33
33
33
```

The data in the New text files is - `Hi How are you!!!!!!`

I expect the output to be the integers which is utf equivalent to above each characters. Kindly let me know if my understanding is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Here

```
  while ((objIpStream.read())!=-1)
    {
        System.out.println(objIpStream.read());
    }
```

You are reading 2 bytes insteed of one. First one is read in the condition and second in body of the loop.
WHat you should do is

```
byte b;
      while ((b=objIpStream.read())!=-1)
        {
            System.out.println(b);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your misunderstanding comes from the fact that you think bytes are characters; they are not.

In order to read characters, you have to convert your bytes to characters first, and this is done using a process known as character encoding. An `InputStream` won't perform this operation, but a `Reader` will.

Therefore, try and:

```
final Path path = Paths.get("F:\\Files\\New.txt");

try (
    final BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(path,
        StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
) {
    int c;
    while ((c = reader.read()) != -1)
        System.out.println(c);
}
```

Also, in your original code, you read *two bytes* per loop.